# Choose CC recipients to receive Cognito Form email notification

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I have a Cognito Form send out the responses to a list of people on a CC list?

I can currently use the email notification settings, and sometimes we need to notify people about new submissions, however, they're not the main recipients of the form.

Is there a way to explicitly add a list of email addresses to CC?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can use the email notification field as a 'CC' for other email addresses. You have the ability to add more then one email in the "To" field by separating each email address with a semicolon (;).

You are welcome to submit a [Feature Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest/) with some specific use cases for a dedicated 'CC' field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Yes, we'll use the email notification field as a 'CC' for now. Considering email conventions, it would be even better if we could differentiate 'TO' and 'CC'.